# I using flask and l cant display images in pythonanywhere but its working on local network

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

```
image=url_for('static',filename=f'users/{user}/usersimages/{image}')
    return f"<img src='{image}'>"
```

I checked path and there is a image at this path its working in local network but not in pythonanywhere

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXaJK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not serving static files. Search the PythonAnywhere help pages for 'static files' for lots of help.